# Is there any possibility to Merage element in sublist with another one by using certain condition?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, nested, extend, del

### merge element of sublist with another sublist without duplicate

---

I am working on solving the vehicle routing problem and get the initial best solution and I want to be exploited and need to get rid of duplicate nodes while merging them.
my problem I want to merge the sublist of element [8] with others that carry the condition equal to 3 elements, but cause there are two sets consist 3 elements like [18, 22, 34, 8], [35, 36, 37, 8] and I need integrate element 8 in one of them randomly

```
bestsolution= [[22, 15, 20, 2, 32, 30, 4, 17], [27, 8, 9, 14, 33, 21, 5, 13], [26, 28, 6, 31, 11], [18,22,34],[35,36,37],[8]]                              
for a in bestsolution:
    if len(a)==1: 
        p=a 
        del bestsolution[-1]         
        for b in bestsolution:  
            if len(b)==2: 
                b.extend(p) 
                print("p",b)
                print("bestsolution1-2",bestsolution)
            elif len(b)==3:
                b.extend(p) 
                print("p",b)
                print("bestsolution1-3",bestsolution)    
    my results:
    p [18, 22, 34, 8]
bestsolution1-3 [[22, 15, 20, 2, 32, 30, 4, 17], [27, 8, 9, 14, 33, 21, 5, 13], [26, 28, 6, 31, 11], [18, 22, 34, 8], [35, 36, 37]]
p [35, 36, 37, 8]
bestsolution1-3 [[22, 15, 20, 2, 32, 30, 4, 17], [27, 8, 9, 14, 33, 21, 5, 13], [26, 28, 6, 31, 11], [18, 22, 34, 8], [35, 36, 37, 8]]
```

where for each run program, I got two results at the same time so how could be refuse the second solution.

'''

```
code targeted:
    bestsolution1-3 [[22, 15, 20, 2, 32, 30, 4, 17], [27, 8, 9, 14, 33, 21, 5, 13], [26, 28, 6, 31, 11], [18, 22, 34], [35, 36, 37, 8]]
'''
```

Thank you

Comment: What is "The vehicle routing problem"? What do you mean "be exploited"?

Comment: "The vehicle routing problem" refers to the field in which I work and "exploited" ta meaning invest the best solution to improve it.

Comment: If either of those things are *relevant* to understanding your question, you should be much more explicit about what they actually mean, *in the question*. If they're not, then they shouldn't be included at all. Even with your answer below, I still have no idea on earth what you were asking. You seem to be including many lines that aren't code in your code blocks, and I don't understand what they're for. You want to be as explicit and clear about the problem you're actually having as possible so that others can understand and help! But glad you seem to have gotten it sorted =)

Answer (score 0):

Ans/
The code will be:
'''

```
bestsolution= [[22, 15, 20, 2, 32, 30, 4, 17],[2,3,4], [27, 8, 9, 14, 33, 21, 5, 13], [26, 28, 6, 31, 11], [18,22,34],[35,36,37],[8]]    
    if len(a)==1: 
        p=a 
        del bestsolution[-1]        
        for b in bestsolution:  
            if len(b)==2: 
               b.extend(p) 
               print("p",b)
               print("bestsolution1-2",bestsolution)
               break
            elif len(b)==3:
               b.extend(p) 
               print("p",b)
               print("bestsolution1-3",bestsolution)
               break
            elif len(b)==4:
               b.extend(p) 
               print("p",b)
               print("bestsolution1-4",bestsolution)
               break
```

'''
Output expected:

```
p [18, 22, 34, 8]
bestsolution1-3 [[22, 15, 20, 2, 32, 30, 4, 17], [27, 8, 9, 14, 33, 21, 5, 13], [26, 28, 6, 31, 11], [18, 22, 34, 8], [35, 36, 37]]
```

'''
After trying much time I got final results, really didn't expect that I solved by putting the keyword (Break)  will prevent execute the program in the second iteration so we will get one solution only.
if anyone have a comment, it will be a pleasure.